# lldb error: Couldn't lookup symbols. Swift iOS

Tags: swift, debugging, lldb

With lldb, I want to instantiate a Swift Class in my release iOS build and release dynamic framework.

I attach lldb to my release build, on the Simulator.

**Main app - works**

```
(lldb) exp let $c = hello_class()
error: <EXPR>:3:10: error: use of unresolved identifier 'hello_class'
let $c = hello_class()
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
(lldb) expr import My_App
(lldb) exp let $c = hello_class()
(lldb) po $c.hello()
 hello
```

**dynamic framework - fails**

```
(lldb) dclass -m myframework
Dumping classes
************************************************************
myframework.RustyAppInfo

(lldb) expr import myframework
(lldb) expr let $d = RustyAppInfo()
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __T011myframework12RustyAppInfoCACycfC
```

Both the app and dynamic framework were built with no optimization.

***UPDATE***

**static framework - fails**

Same results when changing - to the Xcode 9 introduced feature - static Swift framework.

**Xcode - Dead Code Stripping**

by default, with Swift code, `Dead Code Stripping` is turned ON.  I checked to see if that was the issue.  No difference to results.

Comment: Interesting! Maybe edit the question to contain "from framework when attaching it in the debugger" or so to be more specific and hopefully attract specialists :)

Comment: That symbol is: `myframework.RustyAppInfo.__allocating_init() -> myframework.RustyAppInfo`.  That seems like a reasonable thing to want to call when creating a new object, but I'm not sure why it isn't present in your framework.

Comment: I had failed to declare my Framework's init function as public @JimIngham.  That was the reason behind not being able to find the symbol.

Answer (score 2):

***RESOLVED***

I found my answer inside of this article:

http://iosbrain.com/blog/2018/01/13/building-swift-4-frameworks-and-including-them-in-your-apps-xcode-9/

I had failed to set `public init()` on the Swift class that was inside the Framework. Working code that can be invoked by lldb:

```
// set the Framework class to Public
public class rnHello{  

   // set the initializer to public, otherwise you cannot invoke class
    public init() {  

    }

    // set the function to public, as it defaults to internal
    public static func world() {  
        print("hello from a static method")
    }
}
```

Now you can access this via your Swift code or with lldb:

```
(lldb) po rnHello.world()
hello from a static method
```

Comment: Note that the problem wasn't that the method was private per se.  lldb's expression parser can call methods regardless of whether they are public or private.  The problem here was that since the init was not public, the compiler knew it could reason about all its uses, and so didn't need to emit unused flavors, including one that it needed to make the object from lldb.  When you make the init public, swift can no longer reason about its uses, and instead has to emit anything that might be called.